# How to select key from array javascript and return array result

Tags: javascript

How to select data in javascript array as PHP?

```
var myarray = [
            {name:"Nita",id:"001"},
            {name:"Lyda",id:"002"},
            {name:"Lika",id:"003"}
          ];
select(name,id).from(myarray).where(name like %L%);
```

How to select data like this?

Comment: ECMAScript/JavaScript does not support such "LINQ syntax" in the standard API (and it would have to be more akin to `where("name like %L%")` or `where(like("name", "%L%"))`, or whatnot, to avoid syntax issues). Some third-party libraries might, but.. asking for a library is generally Too Board and/or a request to find an Off-site resource. However, check out [lodash](https://lodash.com/) / underscore and the multitude of similar projects, which provider many sequence manipulation methods.

Comment: (And I'm not really sure where "as PHP" comes from.. that's not valid PHP. Maybe a specific PHP library allows something similar?)

Comment: Interesting read: https://ardalis.com/javascript-es6-linq-equivalents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a combination of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (with string [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var myarray = [{name:"Nita",id:"001",age:52},
               {name:"Lyda",id:"002",age:34},
               {name:"Lika",id:"003",age:20}];

// select(name,id).from(myarray).where(name like %L%);
var res = myarray
          .filter(d => d.name.match('L'))
          .map(({name, id}) => ({name, id}));
       
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

User [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) as "where" and [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) as "select". Write the function to achieve whatever you want. For example, to select only the `id` where `name` contains `L` you can write:

```js
var myarray = [
            {name:"Nita",id:"001"},
            {name:"Lyda",id:"002"},
            {name:"Lika",id:"003"}
          ];
var result = myarray.filter( x => x.name.includes("L")).map( x => x.id)
console.log(result)
```